# Finding vowels in a string in java then printing the amount

Tags: java

I have to write a program that takes a string then counts all of the individual vowels. It should print out how many a's, e's, i's, o's, u's and everything else. 
My code is as follows

```
import java.util.*;

public class VowelsInString {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int placeInString = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    int u = 0;
    int nV = 0;
    String myString;

    System.out.println("Enter a string.");
    myString = scan.nextLine();

    while(placeInString <= myString.length())
    {
        if(myString.charAt(placeInString) == 'a')
        {
            a ++;
        }
        else if(myString.charAt(placeInString) == 'e')
        {
            e ++;
        }
        else if(myString.charAt(placeInString) == 'i')
        {
            i ++;
        }
        else if(myString.charAt(placeInString) == 'o')
        {
            o ++;
        }
        else if(myString.charAt(placeInString) == 'u')
        {
            u ++;
        }
        else
        {
            nV ++;
        }

        placeInString ++;

    }
    System.out.println("Numbber of a's in string: " + a);
    System.out.println("Numbber of e's in string: " + e);
    System.out.println("Numbber of i's in string: " + i);
    System.out.println("Numbber of o's in string: " + o);
    System.out.println("Numbber of u's in string: " + u);
    System.out.println("Numbber of non-vowels's in string: " + nV);



}
```

}

My output is

Enter a string.
aaaaeeeeiiiooouuuuggdgds

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 24
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at VowelsInString.main(VowelsInString.java:24)
```

What is my problem and how can I fix it? I'm in a beginner's java class and we just started loops. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it `<` instead of `<=` ?

Comment: You should use a `for` loop instead of the `while` loop: `for (int placeInString = 0; placeInString < myString.length(); placeInString++)`

Answer (score 3):

```
 while(placeInString <= myString.length())
```

Change to

```
 while(placeInString <= myString.length()-1)
```

or

```
while(placeInString < myString.length())
```

Strings are 0 indexed. If you have a string of length 4, and try to access the character at str.length() (which is 4), you're trying to access the 5th element, which is out of bounds. The last character in a string will always be at index str.length()-1.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that can be applied:

```
String  str="hi How Aa rEe YoOuU";   
System.out.println("No. of vowels: " + (str.length() - str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u", "").length()));
```

Output:

```
No. of vowels: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can comma seperate your variable declarations, and you might prefer to use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to avoid accessing the character after the last (which is `String.length() - 1`) with something like

```
int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0, nV = 0;
System.out.println("Enter a string.");
String myString = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase(); // <-- assuming you need capital
                                                 // vowels to count.
for (char ch : myString.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch == 'a') {
        a++;
    } else if (ch == 'e') {
        e++;
    } else if (ch == 'i') {
        i++;
    } else if (ch == 'o') {
        o++;
    } else if (ch == 'u') {
        u++;
    } else {
        nV++;
    }
}
```